# Yii2-Imagine Widget : Image Resize

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-widget

I installed Yii2-Imageine for resizing images for wherever I need in my website using `php composer.phar require --prefer-dist yiisoft/yii2-imagine "*"` command.

In this, I can create multiple images of multiple size. Which Is OK.

But, what I was looking for : Single Image I can re-size it in various places of my website.

So, I tried.

```
use yii\imagine\Image;
use Imagine\Image\Box;
use Imagine\Gd;
use Imagine\Image\BoxInterface;

$image = Image::frame($profile_picture)->thumbnail(new Box(10, 10))->show("jpeg");
<img src="<?=$image?>">
```

But, it **outputs** Like this:

> ����JFIF��>CREATOR: gd-jpeg v1.0 (using IJG JPEG v80), default
>   quality ��C    $.'
>   ",#(7),01444'9=82<.342��C 
>   2!!22222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222��
>   "��
>   ���}!1AQa"q2���#B��R��$3br�
>   %&'()*456789:CDEFGHIJSTUVWXYZcdefghijstuvwxyz���������������������������������������������������������������������������
>   ���w!1AQaq"2�B���� #3R�br�
>   $4�%�&'()*56789:CDEFGHIJSTUVWXYZcdefghijstuvwxyz��������������������������������������������������������������������������?ӷ��n�K-���إ��Q�C�z����ݎ�99_������5�>e}O���Jm:s��U�G��Imagine\Gd\Image
>   Object ( [resource:Imagine\Gd\Image:private] => Resource id #220
>   [layers:Imagine\Gd\Image:private] => )

Where as, when i do

```
print_r(Image::frame($profile_picture)->thumbnail(new Box(10, 10))->show("jpeg"));
die;
```

It shows image with 10*10 dimensions.

So, my question is why such output coming in `<img>` tag. How can i remove those `...2��C  2!!.....` lines and show re-sized image.

Any help/hint/suggestions are appreciable.

Comment: here the same problem, would appreciate if someone would help. thx

Answer (score -1):

this might be helpful to you.

```
use yii\imagine\Image;
use Imagine\Image\Box;
use Imagine\Gd;
use Imagine\Image\BoxInterface;

$image = $imagine->open($profile_picture); 
$image = Image::frame($profile_picture)->thumbnail(new Box(10, 10))->save($thumbnail, ['quality' => 50]);

<img src="<?=$image?>">
```

Or Else try

```
use yii\imagine\Image;
use Imagine\Image\Box;

 ...

$imagine = Image::getImagine()
->open($resizeImagePath)
->thumbnail(new Box(10, 10))
->save($thumbnailImagePath, ['quality' => 90]);
```

Comment: No *@Vijay Bhai*, I don't want to save. What I want is : Same image I wanted to use in different place with my given dimensions. What you have given is to save separate image with separate dimensions. So, unnecessary, My space will get filled with repetitive images.